# delete nodes from xml efficiently

Tags: xml, t-sql, xpath, xml.modify

Here's a challange. 
The code below shows a working method of deleting some rows from an xml variable.
The intention is to delete the rows which do not have the primaryKey attribute set to 1, where the oldValue and newValue attributes are the same. (by the same I mean, both can be null or both having the same value)   The code below demonstrates this happening.   However, the code below makes use of a cursor.
It would not surprise me if it was possible to perform the delete using a single @xml.modify or at least without having to resort to using the cursor.

```
declare @xml xml ='<changes schemaName="Security" tableName="AccessProfiles">
  <column name="AccessProfileId" primaryKey="1" oldValue="114" newValue="114" />
  <column name="AccessProfileName" oldValue="test" newValue="Testing" />
  <column name="DeleteMeSame" oldValue="testValue" newValue="testValue" />
  <column name="DeleteMeNull" />
  <column name="KeepMePrimaryNull" primaryKey="1" />
  <column name="KeepMePrimarySame" primaryKey="1" oldValue="sameValue" newValue="sameValue"/>
</changes>';

declare @columnName sysname;

declare deleteNodesCursor cursor fast_forward for
    with shreddedXml as (
        select
            N.value( '@name' , 'sysname' ) as name,
            N.value( '@primaryKey' , 'bit' ) as primaryKey,
            N.value( '@oldValue' , 'varchar(max)' ) as oldValue,
            N.value( '@newValue' , 'varchar(max)' ) as newValue
        from @xml.nodes('/changes/column') as T(N)
    )
    select
        Name
    from shreddedXml
    where primaryKey is null
    and (oldValue = newValue
    or  (oldValue is null and newValue is null))

open deleteNodesCursor

while (1=1)
begin
    fetch next from deleteNodesCursor into @columnName
    if @@fetch_status != 0
        break;

    set @xml.modify( 'delete /changes[1]/column[@name= sql:variable("@columnName")]' )
end;

close deleteNodesCursor;
deallocate deleteNodesCursor;

select @xml
```

In summary, the question is, how can I accomplish this efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"The intention is to delete the rows which do not have the primaryKey attribute set to 1, where the oldValue and newValue attributes are the same. (by the same I mean, both can be null or both having the same value)"*

That can be translated into a single `@xml.modify` expression as follow (tested and worked in SQL Server 2008R2) :

```
set @xml.modify('delete /changes/column[not(@primaryKey=1) and not(@oldValue!=@newValue)]')
```

Comment: Close.  The <column name="DeleteMeNull" />  is still there and shouldn't be. But I think you've given me enough to go on and solve the problem.

Comment: @ColinDawson ah, you're right! Updated my answer to cover that case

Comment: I've taken the xml above and found modified it, like this.  set @xml.modify('delete /changes/column[not(@primaryKey=1) and ((@oldValue=@newValue) or (empty(@oldValue) and empty(@newValue)))]' )

Comment: Just seen your updated answer.  I like that better as it's less verbose.

Comment: In the end used my more verbose comment as the answer was deleting values incorrectly.